# Do Turks need a visa when travelling to Germany?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, turkish-citizens

I have a Turkish passport. I have a three-day visit to Germany. I am not a citizen of the European Union. Can I do it without a Schengen visa? Is there a special type of visa for this?

Comment: What country issued your passport?

Comment: I have a Turkey passport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Citizens of Turkey require a visa](https://tuerkei.diplo.de/tr-tr/service/05-VisaEinreise) to visit Germany. You only need the regular short-stay Schengen visa. The official German Embassy in Ankara web site has the [instructions of how to apply for the visa](https://tuerkei.diplo.de/tr-tr/service/05-VisaEinreise/-/1514562) (also [in Arabic](https://tuerkei.diplo.de/tr-ar/service/05-VisaEinreise/0-schengenvisa/1541158)).

Comment: I looked to see if there was any other way but I couldn't find it. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @sadikkaplan Turkish service providers don't need visas to travel to the EU, however, in a fairly obscure exception to the general rule.

Comment: @phoog I heard the same thing, but I couldn't find any useful information about it.

Comment: @phoog and Michael. Persons with burgundy passports must obtain any kind of visa. I thank both of you for your interest.